# Php doesn't insert/post empty value, but still insert/post filled value

Tags: php, mysql

Before asking, here's my form picture:
[image]

As you can see, I have 1 form with 2 tables, in each table, there are six inputs.

The input code in "Table Alat" and "Table Bahan" is like this:

```
<form method='post' action='p_input.php'>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='nama[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='merk[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='kemasan[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='mhs[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='jml[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='hps[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'>
        <input type='hidden' name='jenis[]' value='alat' autocomplete='off'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='nama[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='merk[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='kemasan[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='mhs[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='jml[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='hps[]' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'>
        <input type='hidden' name='jenis[]' value='bahan' autocomplete='off'></td>
    </tr>
    <table width='100%' align='center' style='margin-top:0;'>
    <tr>
    <td><input name='reset' type='reset' id='bersihkan' value='Reset'>
    <input name='submit' type='submit' id='ajukan' value='Send'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </table>
    </form>
```

The difference in here is `<input type='hidden' name='jenis[]' value='alat' autocomplete='off'>`, for "Table Alat" the value is 'alat' for "Table Bahan" the value is 'bahan'(I have no trouble in here, just telling you).

This is my `p_input.php` script:

```
 <?php
       error_reporting(0);
       session_start();

        if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        include "../conf/koneksi.php";
        $count = count($_POST['nama']);
        $jurusan = $_POST['jurusan'];
        $lab = $_POST['lab'];
        $materi = $_POST['materi'];
        $mahasiswa= $_POST['mahasiswa'];
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
          $nama = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nama'][$i]);
          $merk = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['merk'][$i]);
          $kemasan = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kemasan'][$i]);
          $mhs = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mhs'][$i]);
          $jml = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jml'][$i]);
          $hps = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hps'][$i]);
          $jenis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jenis'][$i]);
          $sql2= "ALTER TABLE tb_usulan AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
          mysql_query($sql2);
          $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_usulan (nama,merk,kemasan,kebutuhan,jml_kebutuhan,hps,jenis,materi_praktikum)
           VALUES
           ('$nama', '$merk', '$kemasan', '$mhs', '$jml', '$hps','$jenis','$materi')") or die(mysql_error());

        }
        }
        ?>
```

**And my question is**: If I only fill input in "TABLE ALAT" and keep input in "TABLE BAHAN" empty, then when I click submit,  I want only input in table alat to insert/post to database, and vice versa, if I only fill input in "TABLE BAHAN" and keep input in "TABLE ALAT" empty, then only input in "TABLE BAHAN" will insert/post to database.

**UPDATE QUESTION**: This is only one form and one submit button, and insert it to the same table at same time.

Comment: a good way to go around this would be to utilize AJAX since with php/html you can only submit one form per page, with ajax you can have it save to the database without a page refresh.

Comment: ahh sorry sorry, see the edit.
I only use one form for this page. :)

Comment: You can achieve this by changing the feild name in your form.

Comment: Why not just make them 2 different forms?

Comment: @Barmar hope you reply me. can we make two different form. in one page ? Because its seems like that what you are suggesting

Comment: Anyway, you can use `if(!empty($_POST['nama'][$i]))` to check whether that form is filled in.

Comment: you can have as many forms as you want on a page. Give them each their own submit button, and that's the one that will be submitted. Give the submit buttons different values, and the script can tell which form was submitted.

Comment: Or use the hidden field as you already do.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 umm, what do you mean by changing the field name?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for reply. I knew that i though different form with one submit button. Thanks for answering

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy let me check first my solution. if it work i will post. Thanks But yah you can only do that by changing feild name.

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy reply me some thing is your query is working fine?? If that working fine my job going to be easy Thanks

Comment: @Barmar: But if i make their own submit button, it will make it less efficient.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 thanks, yes my query is working fine.

Comment: Are they allowed to fill in both forms, or just one at a time? If they can fill in both, then make it one form, and do what I said with the `empty()` function.

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy i see no submit button Thats why  i am asking

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 ohh sorry, i think i deleted it when i copy my code here, since my original script is too long i edit it to show only my asking part code, i'll edit the code now, and sorry if for 30 minutes or 1 hours i didn't reply, i must pray(shalat) now.

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy dont worry come back i will be here with my solution. make sure you message me when ever you come back. Thanks

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Thanks, i back, i ready for your solution..

Comment: I just wrote the basic structure. Before you try to apply understand it better. and ask me questions. before you go and try to apply i am posting it now. Thanks

Comment: Follow each and every step which i describe in the solution dont understand any thing ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember i added input field. so delete it before you apply the solution. as you already have input feild in your original form.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='nama1' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='merk1' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='kemasan1' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='mhs1' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='jml1' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='hps1' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'>
        <input type='hidden' name='jenis1' value='alat' autocomplete='off'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='nama2' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='merk2' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='kemasan2' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='mhs2' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='jml2' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='hps2' style='width:100%;' autocomplete='off'>
        <input type='hidden' name='jenis2' value='bahan' autocomplete='off'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>


  <input type='submit' name="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Than where you are running the query only change that part.

```
if(!empty($_POST['name1']))
    {
        //Run First query
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['name2']))
    {
        //run your second query
    }
```

**What this code will do it will check for the value. If the values are not empty than it will execute the query other wise it will not execute the query**

**and second** is when you use the code you wont have any array so you need to remove the $count variable. and your foreach loop from the code.

**And Third thing.** you need to set the value after

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        include "../conf/koneksi.php";

For each and every feild like below as i am setting few

$name1=$_Post['name1'];
$merk1=$_post['merk1'];

Do this for each and every value for both table.

**And forth thing** you need to change the value part in your query like your values going to be $name1, and so on for first query and for second query $name2 and so on.

Hope i explain this follow the step. and before following the steps. If you dont understand it ask me before you start applying them.

Thanks

Comment: i use $count and for loop because my table row is dynamic, so if i click "+"(as you can see in the image), it will add a new row.

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy if you use count because of this no worry. Solution will stand same. just some step going to change. You need to use to count for each plus sign lets $count1 and $count2. and yah than dont remove the for loop now which you were using in your original code. as you need count means for loop as well but include for loop in both of your if staement. if you dont know what i am talking about. let me know i will update my answer. Thanks

Comment: yes i think i understand what you means, so i must make loop for each query, right?

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy yes but remove that from the top. and include that in both of your if staement. which i posted in the answer

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy try it let me know as well

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy are you here. I just see where you got the plus sign in your picture. I did not see it before. If you are here let me know Thanks.

Comment: yes, that plus sign is for add new row of my table.

i still try your code, it still save the data even though i didn't fill the input text, maybe i wrong at use it, so i still working at it.

Comment: it's worked already, really thanks friend, i just need to place the 'if(!empty($_POST['name1'][$i]))' inside my loop, thank you very much :D

Comment: @muhammadFahmy . Thanks if you have any problem in future and you are not getting the answer which you want let me know. Thanks

Comment: All right, i hope you can help me again if i had new problem, since my web is still far from finish, i think there will be many problem again, well, thank you again friends.

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy you muslim na so pray for me too. I am not a good muslim. and my email address is arif_suhail_123@yahoo.com you can contact me if you cant get the answer here. but i think you gonna get the answer but if you dont get it let me know

Comment: Alhamdulillah, may Allah be with you, friend. :)
all right, thank you friend, i'll save your email address, so i can contact you if there's any other problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just do a checking inside your for loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    //skip if nama is empty
    if($_POST["nama"][$i] == ""){continue;}

    $nama = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nama'][$i]);
    $merk = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['merk'][$i]);
    $kemasan = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kemasan'][$i]);
    $mhs = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mhs'][$i]);
    $jml = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jml'][$i]);
    $hps = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hps'][$i]);
    $jenis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jenis'][$i]);
    $sql2= "ALTER TABLE tb_usulan AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
    mysql_query($sql2);
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_usulan (nama,merk,kemasan,kebutuhan,jml_kebutuhan,hps,jenis,materi_praktikum)
    VALUES ('$nama', '$merk', '$kemasan', '$mhs', '$jml', '$hps','$jenis','$materi')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: the question is fine. if there's anything wrong with this answer, then it's already a design issue. If OP wants to only POST 1 row, he should not have share the form, unless he's playing with ajax.

Comment: Thanks for helping me friend, but my problem already solved, thanks for take your time for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to separate the tables to separate forms like this:

```
<form name=formOne>
   <table><!-- Alat etc. -->
   </table>
   <input type=submit>
</form>

<form name=formTwo>
   <table><!-- Behan etc. -->
   </table>
   <input type=submit>
</form>
```

then only the table for wich submit is pushed will get submited!

**Edit**
To make it work with only one submit button (client side). 
Add the following jquery:

```
var lastForm;
$("form").click(function(){
     lastForm = this;
});

$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
   $(lastForm).submit();
});
```

You then add the submit button outside of the form elements.
But the nicest solution would be to check the fields serverside. (whitch should be done anyway since you can't really trust the end user).

But that has already been proposed in other answers!

Comment: the submit button is only one, so if when i click the submit button the table bahan is filled and table alat is empty, it will automatically only submit table bahan and ignore table alat.

Comment: You need to add one submit button, as seen in the example above!

Comment: But, it will make it less efficient, since my work place want only one sumbit button, and it was insert to the same table, anyway.

Comment: I didn't say it was the best solution, but it is a working one with almost no effort. The only other solution is to check wich form thats have been filled and then store values accordingly.

Comment: Yes, i think so too, if i make 2 submit button, it will be much easier.

Comment: yeah sorry, but it didn't solve my problem, since my problem is with only one submit button.

Comment: Thanks for helping me friend, but my problem already solved, thanks for take your time for helping me.